# Mysql WHERE OR WHERE started with integer weird results

Tags: php, mysql

why is

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$search' OR `email` = '$search' LIMIT 1";

`id` = UNSIGNED INTEGER(10), `email` = VARCHAR(255)
```

why is the query results so weird, i think the image is self explained, but i need some word too, so here it is, when user search dcm2@example.com or anything else not exists, no results, but if the string start with number and searching the PRIMARY KEY, it turn the string to integer, if i search 2dcm1@example.com, the ID 2 return, any good explaination and why is this happend?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: im using PDO, and let user just search results, never insert in this case, but just i try to explain the case, so i write this

Comment: It distracts from what you're doing. Whenever possible just leave the placeholders as-is. Good news is those passwords look properly hashed, so you've got that part locked down.

Comment: What is the type of the column email?

Comment: varchar(255) for column email

Comment: Since you're comparing integer to string for the id, it's probably converting the string to an integer, which means the 2 at the beginning of the email address matches the 2 in the id. Try `WHERE (CAST id AS varchar) = ...` and see if it works. ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html))

Comment: so, this question is more about *behaviour*, correct?

Comment: yes, i don't even know how to name the title, this doesn't make my website in danger or error or what, but i found it weird so curious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because MySql automatically converts the types whenever an operator is used with operands of different types (assuming that your `id` is an integer column).

See [the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html):

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa.

And the following example (copied from the documentation):

```
mysql> SELECT 1 > '6x';
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT 7 > '6x';
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT 0 > 'x6';
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT 0 = 'x6';
        -> 1
```

Unfortunately there seems to be no configuration to prevent this behaviour (for `SELECT` statements at least). What might work is an explicit cast on your `id` column:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(6 AS CHAR) = '6x';
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT CAST(6 AS CHAR) = 6;
        -> 1
```

But that still seems weird as it enforces a string comparison for an integer column. The better approach would probably be to handle such cases in your php code (as pointed out in the comments).

Comment: any idea how to prevent this? telling mysql don't guess the variable maybe?

Comment: You could try doing an explicit `CAST` so that MySQL doesn't implicitly do it for you on both parameters...

Comment: Or on PHP side, convert it before passing it to MySQL: `is_int($search) ? $search : 0` (assuming 0 is never a valid ID)

Comment: thanks, really increase my knowledge in php/mysql a bit

Comment: @user259752 You are passing a string variable to compare with an integer. First remove the quotes, then you can use CONCAT to check for full integers... $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`id` = $search AND CONCAT('', $search*1) = $search) OR `email` = '$search' LIMIT 1";

Comment: Just noticed reply from this.lau_, it's probably better to do it at PHP side itself, since MySQL does not have an IsNumeric().